# How can I associate an on click function for X number of elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have a table with hundreds of rows, I can assign an id to each row and each component (since the table is dynamically created).
But if e.g. in each row I have a checkbox and I want to associate each checkbox with a function on click to do something in another column in the same row, how do I do that?
Do I have to define for each checkbox an onclick method? And how do I access the other column of the same row?

**Update**:
I tried the suggestion but it does not work. Sample:

```
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
<title>Insert title here</title>  
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>  
<body>  

<table id="main_table" border="1">  
<tr><th>First</th><th>Last</th><th>Modify</th></tr>  
<tr>  
    <td>Jim</td><td><input id="rep1" type="text" disabled value="X"></td><td><input   class=".checkbox" type="checkbox">  </td>  
</tr>  
</table>  
</body>  
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).delegate('change', "#main_table :checkbox", function(){    
    console.log("In function");  
    if(this.checked){ //If you want to perform checked check  

        alert("Hello");    
    }  
});   


</script>  

</html>
```

**Update 2:**
The following also does not work:

```
$("#main_table ").delegate('click', ":checkbox", function(){  
    console.log("In function");  
    if(this.checked){ //If you want to perform checked check  

        alert(parentTd);   
    }  
});
```

**Update 3:**
The following also works:

```
$("#main_table ").on('click', ":checkbox", function(){  
    console.log("In function");  
    if(this.checked){ //If you want to perform checked check  

        alert(parentTd);   
    }  
});
```

Seems like `delegate` does not work? Can anyone explain to me what have I been messing up?

Comment: @MohammadAdil:I got stuck to the table.I googled and found that I can associate using the id an onclick method but I can not understand how this can happen for hundrends of elements (1 per row)

Comment: You have the arguments to `delegate` in the wrong order. It's `delegate(selector, event, handler)`. You have the arguments in the order that `on` uses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign a single handler for all of them. In the handler, `$(this)` is the element that was clicked on to trigger the handler, and you can then use DOM traversal methods to find other elements related to it, e.g.

```
$("#yourtable").on("click", ".checkbox", function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").find(".destination").text("Clicked on checkbox in this row");
});
```

This example assumes there's a checkbox with `class="checkbox"` in each row, and another field with `class="destination"`.

UPDATE: Using your HTML:

```
$("#main_table").on("click", ".checkbox", function () {
    alert($(this).closest("tr").find("input[type=text]").val());
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/kv33y/11/)

Comment: I also get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' `

Comment: `.on()` has been available since jQuery 1.7. I can't explain why you're getting that error, since you're using 1.7.

Comment: Make sure all this code is inside the `$(document).ready()` handler. Although I don't think that is related to your error.

Comment: I changed the CDN to point to 1.7.But now it simply does not do anything. (I don't get the error though)

Comment: It should be `class="checkbox"`, not `class=".checkbox"`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use  [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). You have to use [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) using delegated-events approach.

You can try something like

```
$(document).on('change', "#tableId :checkbox", function(){  
    if(this.checked){ //If you want to perform checked check
        var parentTd = $(this).closest('td');
        var siblingTd = parentTd.siblings()
    }
});
```

Also check [**.siblings()**](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [**.closest(**)](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

### EDIT

As per comment `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'`

It seems you are using < jQuery 1.7, use [.delegate()](https://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
 $(elements).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
```

In Your case

```
$(document).delegate("#tableId :checkbox", 'change', function() {
      //You code
});
```

Comment: @Jim, for delegated events you don't need `$(document).ready`

Comment: Is it `$(document).on`?I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on' `

Comment: @Jim, It seems you are using __< jQuery 1.7__ so use `delegate()` I have updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You need event delegation. Attach your `click` event to a parent that exists on the page, such as maybe the table element:

```
$('#myTable').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (e) {
     ... run some code here ...
});
```

Then let the checkbox events bubble up to that parent.

For ***jQuery 1.7+***: [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

You would use [delegated events](https://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). For example:

```
$("#myTable").on("click", ":checkbox", function() { ... });
```

The click handler will be attached to one element only (the table) but will respond to clicks on all of the checkboxes nested inside it (and *only* the checkboxes).

Inside the event handler `this` will be bound to the checkbox that was clicked, so you can start from `$(this)` and traverse the DOM to find any other elements of interest.